About adding random effects in Multilevel (HLM) analysis
I am doing regression analysis in HLM. I am wondering whether random effects should be added in this process.
Let me ask a question using a famous example. LV1 is a student and LV2 is a school. LV1 variable is household income and LV2 is public/private. Dependent variable is grades. 'And there are some lv1 control variables.'
I want to analyze the interaction between household income and school type. In this case, the reason why I include random slope effect is because, as far as I know, there is variation in household income 'effect' by school that is not explained by school type variable and interaction variable.
Unless I am (unreasonably) claiming that school type variable and interaction variable can theoretically explain all variation in household income by school, should I include random slope effect in HLM analysis?

If the sample size is limited and there is a possibility of model stability problems, 2) If you want to focus on fixed effects and keep the model simpler and easier to interpret, 3) If the model with the random slope effect added does not show better BIC, is it wrong to analyze the model excluding the random slope effect for these practical reasons?

Furthermore, if I analyze the model including the random slope effect and the analysis results show that the random slope effect is insignificant, does this mean that my data is not suitable for HLM? In other words, even if the interaction term itself is significant, if the random slope effect is insignificant, did I use the wrong methodology in the first place?
...
PS. After hearing the comments below, I have revised some of the expressions.
I apologize for the confusion regarding the expression. My question is whether I need to include a random slope in the model, given that a random intercept is already included in the model.

Are you also allowing the intercept to vary randomly? Some of your language implies that you are only including random slopes, but not random intercepts, which would be very unusual. Even if you didn't include random slopes, a model that had a school-level random intercept would still be an "HLM" model (unless you are talking about HLM the program?)

Yes, the slope for the level 1 (student) variable should be random. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/463883/interaction-withinbetween-in-mixed-models-slope-of-the-within-factor-as-random/464346#464346 and also this simulation study by Heisig & Schaffer (2019). https://academic.oup.com/esr/article-abstract/35/2/258/5306121

TLDR: As I noted in my comment, you should specify the lower level variable's slope as varying randomly across higher level units. There are at least two reasons for this. The first is conceptual and the second is statistical.
Conceptually, you are interested in whether the slope of a lower level variable, here household income, varies as a function of a cluster-level variable, school type. Accordingly, a first order idea is that the strength and direction of the income slope varies across clusters. And you want to test whether the strength and direction of the slope can be explained by the school track. It can be helpful to write out the equation in the manner of Raudenbush & Bryk's HLM formula to see why this makes sense:
Within-schools:
$grade_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j}income_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$
Between-schools:

$\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}schtype_j + u_{0j}$
$\beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10} + \gamma_{11}schtype_j + u_{1j}$

In this formulation, it is very clear that school type is a predictor of the random intercept, $\beta_{0j}$, and the random slope, $\beta_{1j}$.
Statistically, the issue is addressed directly in the Heisig & Schafer (2019) paper I referenced in my comment. They find that in mixed effects models with cross-level interactions, the absence of a random slope for the lower level variable leads to standard error estimates that are too liberal. That is, the standard error you get from such a model without the random slope will be biased and more likely to lead to rejections of null hypothesis that the interaction is 0 when it is not. Accordingly, even if the random slope is itself not significant based on likelihood ratio testing nor warranted based on AIC or BIC, you still need to include it.
Taking a step back, what would it mean that a random slope is not warranted based on model testing? It would mean that there is little evidence in your data to support the idea that the slope of interest varies across clusters. It might be that in the population, the slope does vary across clusters but you have too little data or have sampled schools where this is not the case. Unfortunately, there is not a lot of evidence to even investigate the cross-level interaction in your data because the first order issue (slope variability) is not supported.
You asked questions about sample size and model stability. These are important concerns, and there are all sorts of small sample size methods for frequentist mixed models (REML estimation with Kenward-Roger standard errors). You could go full Bayesian with strong priors about the random slope and cross-level interaction. The issue of interpretability is a non-issue in my opinion as long as you explain the conceptual logic of the random slope and the cross-level interaction.

Your answer was really helpful, thanks!
I think the main reason the random effect wasn't significant in my data is the sample size per level 2, which is under 10. So, I'm going to try using Clustered Standard Errors. Do you think it's okay to use this method for interactions between level 1 and level 2?

Yes, you can use a single level regression model with clustered standard errors. I personally would not do that. I don't think that your L1 sample size/L2 cluster is too small to get valid random effect parameter estimates. Are you using REML estimation, which is the default in lme4::lmer()? If instead you are using Stata, then you need to include the option reml in the mixed model statement.

FWIW for me your phrasing is slightly off target:
You say:

there is variation in household income by school that is not explained by school type variable and interaction variable

But your DV is grades ... so the question is not about variation in income but variation in grades being "explained by" variation in income and/or the interaction of income with school type.
Also, your fixed effects model seems to me to be:
$$ grades=intercept + income + schoolType+income*schoolType + error $$
But in theory terms I'd question this ... unless you have some randomisation process that is eliminating all of the other factors that would affect grades or some rationale for why all additional variables can be allocated to "error".
Can you be explicit about the clustering? It is random effects between schools or between students or something else?
IMO the addition of a random affect should be based on theory and/or a plan to generalise results beyond the given sampled contexts.
Two cent ... :-)

The post is pretty explicit about clustering IMO - "LV1 is a student and LV2 is a school". So students nested within schools.

Depending on the wider context (AFAIK) you could have random slopes for each school type or random slopes for each student ... hence my query ... but ... I accept that you are likely correct! Particularly given that this would be a common example.

Sure, in some cases, but they said school type only has two levels, in which case it shouldn't be put in as random effect, and nothing implied they had repeated measures per student.
